# How to skip mail that has ANY category tag, but process mail that has no tag?

Tags: email, excel, outlook, vba

So I am trying to say if an email has a category then go to PASS_MAIL. But the below code does not work.

```
If Not IsEmpty(mail.Categories) Then GoTo PASS_MAIL
```

This code works as it targets a specific category, but I dont want that. I want it to target ANY category that a mail has.

```
If mail.categories = "ATLG" Then GoTo PASS_MAIL
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsEmpty` is used to determine if individual variable is initialized or not. You may want to see [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227.aspx)

Use this. This works for me.

```
If Not mail.Categories = "" Then GoTo PASS_MAIL
```